# How is mixed precision managed with order of operations in Python

Tags: python

If I write something like

```
x = ((3 * 3) + 1) + 7.2
```

are the operations performed in parentheses carried out in integer arithmetic or floating point arithmetic? I know for this case it does not matter, but in general, it might if the integer calculation can be perfectly represented, but the float cannot.

Comment: If the operation is between two integers, integer arithmetic is used. If the operation is between an integer and a float or two floats, floating-point arithmetic is used. Regular [order of operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) is used to decide which to do first.

Comment: What an operation does is determined solely by the types of its operands.  Types used elsewhere in the same expression are not relevant.

Comment: An arithmetic operation is applied to the arguments given to it. Multiplying an integer by an integer results in an integer; there's no look ahead to know that a float is coming later.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi the exception is division